# Sprockets::FileNotFound - couldn't find file 'jquery.ui'

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sprockets

This has been asked a few times, but I tried the solutions provided and they still didn't help, so I'm asking a new question.

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

As suggested, I placed my gem outside the `:assets` group

**Application.css~**

```
 *= require_self
 *= require jquery.ui
 *= require bootstrap-datepicker
 *= require jquery.timepicker
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

The `Rails Asset Pipeline` loads assets based on the order they are listed. Here, I have it at number 2 on the list.

**Application.css.scss**

```
*= require_self
*= require fullcalendar
*= require jquery.ui
*= require fullcalendar_engine/application
```

**Application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require wice_grid
//= require turbolinks
//= require fullcalendar
```

Once again, `jquery.ui` is loaded immediately after `jquery`.

I also ran `bundle list` to ensure my gems are up to date.

```
jquery-rails (3.1.2)
jquery-ui-rails (5.0.3)
```

I am using the updated versions of these gems. Also, I no longer type in `jquery.ui.all`

It looks like I've followed most of the suggestions from previous answers, but to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second line in your application.css file should be:

```
 *= require jquery-ui
```

not

```
 *= require jquery.ui
```

dash not dot, [see here](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails#require-everything).

Same with your application.js file:

```
//= require jquery-ui
```